# Which package provides a certain configuration file?

Tags: debian, apt, dpkg

Is there an analog for `dpkg -S <file>`, but for configuration files, such as `/etc/samba/smb.conf`? Which are generated on `dpkg-reconfigure`, I guess.

```
user@host:~$ dpkg -S /etc/samba/smb.conf
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`dpkg -S` will only find configuration files which are shipped directly in packages, not those which are generated by maintainer scripts (or other tools). There’s no general solution for the latter, but looking for references to the file in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` is your best bet. In this instance:

```
$ grep -rl /etc/samba/smb.conf /var/lib/dpkg/info
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.config
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/samba-common.templates
```

This suggests that the file is managed by `samba-common`; reading the `postinst` file will confirm that.

Comment: Searching on `/etc/sudoers` reports for `/var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.conffiles` file. Should I be concerned or I shall be looking for `.postinst` files only?

Comment: That’s normal, `snapd` ships `/etc/sudoers.d/99-snapd.conf`, which matches `/etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 7):

Stephen Kitt's answer is probably the best, but if you can't find it like that, you can also try `etckeeper`. This is not installed by default on Debian and Ubuntu, but it is in the repo's so a simple `apt install etckeeper` should do it.

Etckeeper puts your `/etc` under (git) version control. One of the things it does is make an automatic commit every time you install/update a package.

Now you can use `cd /etc && sudo git blame somefile` to see when it was adjusted and search that date in `/var/log/dpkg*`

It's a lot of work, but it should work when `dpkg -S` doesn't find it.

Comment: Using `etckeeper` is always good advice ;-).